# Javascript - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Tags: javascript

In getting error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL` only in my production server (localhost works properly).

Anyone have any idea where the error come from?

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function submitEnter(event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            sendForm();
            return false;
        }
    }

    function sendForm() {
        $('#btnSend').prop('disabled', true);
        $('#btnSend').val('Adicionando...');
        var data=$("#chipForm").serialize();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '<?php echo Yii::app()->createAbsoluteUrl("chip/create"); ?>',
            data: data,
            success:function(data){
                if (data=='success') {
                    var sound = new Audio(<?php echo Yii::app()->baseUrl; ?>'/sounds/success.wav');
                    sound.play();

                    $('#chipsCount').val( parseInt($('#chipsCount').val()) + 1 );
                } else {
                    var sound = new Audio(<?php echo Yii::app()->baseUrl; ?>'/sounds/failure.wav');
                    sound.play();
                }
                $('#Chip_ICCID').val('');
                $('#Chip_ICCID').focus();

                $('#btnSend').prop('disabled', false);
                $('#btnSend').val('Adicionar');
            },
            error: function(data) {
                alert("Error occured.please try again");
                $('#btnSend').prop('disabled', false);
                $('#btnSend').val('Adicionar');
            },
            dataType:'html'
        });
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line

```
var sound = new Audio(<?php echo Yii::app()->baseUrl; ?>'/sounds/success.wav');
```

should look like

```
var sound = new Audio('<?php echo Yii::app()->baseUrl; ?>/sounds/success.wav');
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working properly now! Do you have any idea why it was working on localhost and not in production?

Comment: I got it. `<?php echo Yii::app()->baseUrl; ?` is an empty string in `localhost`! Now everything makes sense :P